# How to avoid dropped frames in AVCaptureSession with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, avcapturesession

I'm setting up an AVCaptureSession in a Xamarin.iOS project, and I get a high percentage of dropped frames regardless of the frame rate I set on the device.  When I strip down the session to use the back camera and only one output (an AVCaptureVideoDataOutput), my delegate's DidOutputSampleBuffer method is only being called maybe 2/3 of the time.  This is true even when I set the max and min frame durations to 1/3 second and essentially gut the delegate methods to do nothing but increment counters.  Sorry for the wall of code that follows, but I don't know what might be wrong where.

capture session setup:

```
AVCaptureDeviceType[] deviceTypes = new AVCaptureDeviceType[] {
AVCaptureDeviceType.BuiltInTrueDepthCamera,
AVCaptureDeviceType.BuiltInDualCamera,
AVCaptureDeviceType.BuiltInWideAngleCamera};
AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySession =
    AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession.Create(deviceTypes,
        AVMediaType.Video, AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back);
AVCaptureDevice[] devices = discoverySession.Devices;
AVCaptureDevice device = devices.FirstOrDefault();
if (device == null)
{
    return false;
}

previewView.VideoPreviewLayer.Session = null;
m_CaptureSession?.Dispose();
m_CaptureSession = new AVCaptureSession();

NSError error;
AVCaptureDeviceInput input = new AVCaptureDeviceInput(device, out error);
if (error == null)
{
    if (m_CaptureSession.CanAddInput(input))
    {
        m_CaptureSession.AddInput(input);
    }

    // note: will try for 120fps on my iPhone 5S, but I've
    // also overridden the settings with a hard-coded 3fps
    // and get the same results (dropping a large percentage
    // of frames)
    ConfigureCameraForHighestFrameRate(device);

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput output = new AVCaptureVideoDataOutput();
    AVVideoSettingsUncompressed settings =
        new AVVideoSettingsUncompressed();
    settings.PixelFormatType = CVPixelFormatType.CV32BGRA;
    output.UncompressedVideoSetting = settings;

    m_OutputQueue = new DispatchQueue("outputQueue", false);
    m_OutputRecorder = new OutputRecorder(device);
    output.SetSampleBufferDelegateQueue(m_OutputRecorder, m_OutputQueue);
    if (m_CaptureSession.CanAddOutput(output))
    {
        m_CaptureSession.AddOutput(output);
    }

    // don't hook up preview view, so we can test the video data
    // output on its own...
    // previewView.VideoPreviewLayer.Session = m_CaptureSession;

    m_CaptureSession.StartRunning();
}
```

delegate methods:

```
public override void DidOutputSampleBuffer(AVCaptureOutput captureOutput,
    CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, AVCaptureConnection connection)
{
    lock (m_Mutex)
    {
        if (!m_Recording)
        {
            return;
        }
        m_FrameCount++;
        return;
    }
}

public override void DidDropSampleBuffer(AVCaptureOutput captureOutput,
    CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer, AVCaptureConnection connection)
{
    lock (m_Mutex)
    {
        if (!m_Recording)
        {
            return;
        }
        m_DroppedFrameCount++;
    }
}
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

So, the problem was apparently that it's the delegate's job to dispose of `sampleBuffer`, and while I was doing that for frames generated while recording, I wasn't for frames captured before recording started.  The solution was to make sure `sampleBuffer` gets disposed regardless of whether the app is recording.  This is probably a Xamarin-specific problem and solution; I don't know if it would be useful to Swift developers.